# show only preloading image inside a display:none div but not div

Tags: jquery, preloader

I  have a div **wrapper_** where results of jquery are displaying

```
<div id='ico_wait' class="ico_wait" style='display: none;' >
     <img src ="img/ico_wait.gif" /> 
</div>


<div id='wrapper_' style='display: none;'>  
</div>
```

in jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#other_stuff').click(function () {
         //show image
         jQuery('#ico_wait').fadeToggle();
         //DO STUFF
         jQuery('#ico_wait').hide();
         //ADD INFO GOTTEN IN WRAPPER
         jQuery('#wrapper_').show();
         jQuery('#wrapper_').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:0px; padding-top:20px;'>  </p> </b><br/> <br/> ");
     });
 })
```

How to add

```
<div id='ico_wait' class="ico_wait" style='display: none;' >
     <img src ="img/ico_wait.gif" /> 
</div>
```

inside wrapper_? so it is contained in the div? I mean, I want to show only the image when executing code not all div, when I finish gettting results then hide image and show whole div?

Comment: You wanting your waiting image to take over the whole page or just a section of the page while waiting?

Comment: I want to show image inside wrapper, but only before I finish and write stuff in the div

Comment: And you are wanting to go away from the two divs to a single div that you load your items in as well as the progress indicator?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I am just trying to figure out the right answer for what you are trying to do.  You have the answer below, you also can swap the content and you can even do a type of async way that makes sure that you are not locking the browser thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand you correctly, you should do the following:

```
<div id='wrapper_' style='display: none;'>  
    <div id='ico_wait' class="ico_wait" >
        <img src ="img/ico_wait.gif" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#other_stuff').click(function () {
        //show image when stuff inside wrapper is being populated
        $('#wrapper_').show();
        //DO STUFF
        //ADD INFO IN WRAPPER when its ready and hide image
        $('#wrapper_ #ico_wait').fadeToggle();
        $('#wrapper_').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:0px; padding-top:20px;'>  </p> </b><br/> <br/> ");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way I would go about this:

CSS

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='wrapper_'> 
    <div id='ico_wait' class="ico_wait" class="hide" >
        <img src ="img/ico_wait.gif" /> 
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#other_stuff').click(function(){
             //show image
             jQuery('#ico_wait').removeClass('hide'); // Use of CSS Styles to do any animation for fading
             //DO STUFF
             jQuery('#ico_wait').addClass('hide');     
             //ADD INFO GOTTEN IN WRAPPER
             jQuery('#wrapper_').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:0px; padding-top:20px;'>  </p> </b><br/> <br/> ");


        });
});
```

I prefer to let the CSS engine do any style updates and changes to the HTML this should run on another thread, not the same JavaScript executing thread so that the animations can go with out any issues, while your JavaScript runs.

You can also do this with content swapping as well with just jQuery, but not sure how well that would be recommended.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#other_stuff').click(function(){
             //show image
             jQuery('#wrapper_').html("<img src='img/ico_wait.gif' />");
             //DO STUFF
             jQuery('#wrapper_').html("<b><p style='color:#5b5b5b; float:left; margin-top:0px; padding-top:20px;'>  </p> </b><br/> <br/> ");


        });
});
```

If you are having async issues with your long running code you could use something like: jQuery Async to help at http://mess.genezys.net/jquery/jquery.async.php

Hope this helps.